# Spammed with errors from asyncpg when discord bot is turned off

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I am trying to integrate asyncpg with discord.py, however I ran into one very anoyying issue.

Whenever I try to stop the bot using ^C, I get spammed with a ton of errors. This is just bothersome as when I'm trying to debug something I often lose the original error.

Here is my code:

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def connection_init(conn):
    await conn.execute("SET CLIENT_ENCODING to 'utf-8';")
    conn.client = client

try:
    client.pool = loop.run_until_complete(asyncpg.create_pool(
        host=os.environ.get("postgres_host"),
        database=os.environ.get("postgres_database"),
        user=os.environ.get("postgres_user"),
        password=os.environ.get("postgres_password"),
        connection_class=dbutils.DBUtils,
        init=connection_init
    ))

    print('PostgreSQL connection successful')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

    # the bot basically cannot function without database
    print('PostgreSQL connection failed- aborting')
    exit()


client.run(os.environ.get("main"))
```

Here are the errors that floods my terminal. It's the same error however it pops up like 20 times.

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x033DF148>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zghan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\zghan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\zghan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\zghan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

That error happens because the `asyncio.get_event_loop()` can not retrieve any loop, as at the moment you try to retrieve it, it is already closed.

The correct syntax would be to start a new loop instead of trying to get the current:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
# ...
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Alternatively, in Python 3.7 asyncio added a new way of managing the loops: using `asyncio.run()`, which does not require you to create, set or retrieve the current loop as it already manages all that internally.

Comment: I tried this out, I'm now no longer able to even stop my bot using control C. I'm pretty sure `client.run()` is using `asyncio.run()` in the background. `client.pool` is the database connection I'm trying to safely close, and `client` is the bot itself.